# Error while check in page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, development, 2016

I am facing a weird issue in SharePoint 2016.

I am creating a page and after creating a page I am redirecting a user to edit the same page.

Now when the user is going to check-in a page after modification, it gives error sometimes (Not always Probably once in creating 15 pages).

Here is an error message.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.   
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPChunkedArray`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.PopulateReturnedFieldsSafeArray()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureFieldsSafeArray(Boolean bGetFullXML)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.get_InternalNameDict()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.get_Item(String fieldName)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetFieldValue(String fieldName)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.WebPartInFieldHelper.get_MayHaveWebParts()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.RichTextField.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.RichHtmlField.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: perhaps there is a field somewhere that exceeds the max characters for that field type? or something field related. are u doing this programatically? if so, the details might help

Comment: No. Nothing programmatically. And if I refresh the page then a page is showing perfect.

Comment: can you share the code that you use to create the page ?

Comment: Page is created successfully. Getting erroe while check-in page from ribbon.